# How to use sorted() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

The code I write like this:
[image]

when I try to run it under python3.6, the error comes:
[image]

But  I'm just coding under the way the python document shows me:
[image]

Is there anyone who can please tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Paste text instead of pictures so answers can copy your code instead of retyping it.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You _do_ need to paste the actual text of your code into the question. Otherwise there is the risk that your question will get downvotes.

Comment: I copy that, thanks @PM2Ring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [the `sorted` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), you need to pass your comparison function as a `cmp` argument not a `key` argument. So

```
sorted(some_list, cmp=cmp_ignore_case)
```

However, using `cmp` is *much* less efficient than `key`, and so `cmp` has been deprecated for some time in Python 2, and it has been removed from Python 3.

A `key` function only gets called once for each unique item in the list (or other iterable) that you're sorting. In contrast, a `cmp` function *must* be called every time a comparison is made between two items.

It's possible to transform a `cmp` function into a `key` function with [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key), but this is only provided for convenience: it doesn't prevent the inefficiency, it only hides it. So it should only be used as a temporary fix for old code that uses `cmp`, or in those rare cases where it's not possible to use a `key` function.

For further details, please see the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

Answer (score 2):

It's right in the documentation you show :

```
>>> sorted(['bob', 'about', 'Zoo', 'Credit'], key=str.upper)
['about', 'bob', 'Credit', 'Zoo']
>>> sorted(['bob', 'about', 'Zoo', 'Credit'], key=str.lower)
['about', 'bob', 'Credit', 'Zoo']
```

The `key` function should only accept one argument : it is called for every single string automatically by `sorted`. Your function expects 2 arguments, and `sorted` doesn't know what `s2` should be.

So your code should be :

```
def ignore_case(just_one_string):
    return just_one_string.upper()

print(sorted(['bob', 'about', 'Zoo', 'Credit'], key=ignore_case))
# ['about', 'bob', 'Credit', 'Zoo']
```

The confusion could come from the fast that in some other languages (e.g. Java), the method expects 2 arguments (see [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html))

Comment: Yes, but, I mean how to implement python2 version code `print(sorted(['bob', 'about', 'Zoo', 'Credit'], cmp_ignore_case))` under python3

Comment: As I wrote, the problem isn't python2 or python3 : it's that `cmp_ignore_case` should have 1 argument, not 2.

Comment: Well, under your prompting, I compared the Built-in function `sorted` in python2.7 and python3.6, and I recognised there's a `cmp` argument in python2, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a custom comparator function for Python 3's `sorted`, you must use `functools.cmp_to_key`, like so:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
sorted(['bob', 'about', 'Zoo', 'Credit'], key=cmp_to_key(cmp_ignore_case))
```

For further information, please refer to the documentation for `functools.cmp_to_key`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key